# Using ngOnChanges to trigger whether to show an overlay depending input changes

Tags: angular, typescript

I work in TS/Angular on a web application. I have decided to refactor some code which determines which determines which overlay to show out of 6 different overlays. I decided to combine all overlays into one and define a function in the new "master overlay" which determines which set of settings should be used to show the 6 different variations of the overlay. The function must evaluate whether to show an overlay whenever any of the variables that determine if an overlay should be shown is changed. There are around 20 variables. So in order to run the function when necessary I decided to make all the 20 variables inputs in my component and to run the function in `ngOnChanges`. I know `ngOnChanges` can be "dangerous" to use as it runs every Angular change detection cycle. However, I feel in this case I have control over the change detection in my component, as it should only update if any of the inputs are updated. Am I wrong for using the `ngOnChanges` under these circumstances?

My team keeps telling me that we do not use `ngOnChanges`, but I feel it is a good fit for this case.

Comment: _I know ngOnChanges can be "dangerous" to use as it runs every Angular change detection cycle_ - this is incorrect. `ngOnChanges` runs on every _input_ change (and once before `ngOnInit`).

Answer (score 0):

> I know ngOnChanges can be "dangerous" to use as it runs every angular change detection cycle

It is wrong, only `ngDoCheck` is run on every cycle.

`ngOnChanges` only triggers when an `@Input` value changed. It is exactly what you want, you're safe !

Answer (score 0):

First i would recomemnd a to remove all the inputs as it would be very hard to track and pass 20 inputs isn't it ? Secondly i would recommend to create a service (or use state ngrx is my  ultimate choice) and in the service have a model (object with all the 20 settings as properties) in the child component you init a subscription to servicees observable and whenever one of them changes you just run change detection( if we assume that you are using onPush)
https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#parent-and-children-communicate-using-a-service